# access duct insulation thickness value

Tags: revit-api

I am writing API for Revit using C#, try to add insulation code for different type and thickness, to be tagged wit duct size.
I can get ductID, InSuID of the duct, and insulation name, however I cannot get value of insulation thickness. Where and how can I get value of insulation thickness? Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some discussions of this topic by The Building Coder:

- [Pipe Insulation and Insulation Material](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/05/pipe-insulation-and-insulation-material.html)
- [What's New in the Revit 2012 API](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/02/whats-new-in-the-revit-2012-api.html)
- [Pipe Insulation Retrieval Performance](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2021/10/sci-fi-languages-and-pipe-insulation-retrieval.html#2)